# Clone a SVG path and put it in an other SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm a real noob in SVG manipulation.
I need to copy a SVG path and paste it in an other svg.
This other SVG will have a different position and a different size.
My problem is when I copy the SVG path it keeps the position and don't stay in my new SVG viewport.

In order to copy the SVG  I use :

```
$('.svg_thumb svg').append($('#head').clone() );
```

You can play with this example : http://jsfiddle.net/uk4c2jqr/

following this example : I would like my head to be in the center of the read square for example 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `transform=translate(x,y)` method :

```
var tb_head = $('#head').clone();
tb_head.attr('transform', 'translate(-325, -85)');
$('.svg_thumb svg').append(tb_head);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk4c2jqr/2/)

**Edit from OP's request** :

In order to calculate the x and y values, the best way would be to refactor your path so that it starts from position 0,0.

But you can find an approximation using the getBoundingClientRect() method :

```
var originalPath = $('#head'),
thumb_head = originalPath.clone(),
thumb_Svg = $('.svg_thumb svg'),
bBox = originalPath[0].getBoundingClientRect(),

xPos = thumb_Svg.width()/2 - bBox.width/2 - bBox.left,
yPos = thumb_Svg.height()/2 - bBox.height/2 - bBox.top;

thumb_head.attr('transform', 'translate('+xPos+','+ yPos+')');
thumb_Svg.append(thumb_head);
```

and [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk4c2jqr/4/)

Comment: how can I compute the -325, -85 ? coz I have a lot of parts and I need to do this programmatically.

Comment: Ok I'll try with the getBoundingClientRect, I think I can manage something with this - BTW your last jsfiddle is not working- . If it's working don't worry I'll be back to accept your answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uk4c2jqr/5/ this one is working thank you so much, can you edit you answer for other people who don't know how to read comments ;)